# Warm up Scripts in sharepoint

Tags: performance, warm-up

I wanted to know and implement warm up scripts in Sharepoint 2010.
Can anyone tell me what are these warm up scripts and why do we need it?

Please provide the script and how to execute the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any .Net application, SharePoint requires a certain time to load the page initially and subsequent requests come faster from the server for the same site.

These are common issues faced by developers when they try accessing the site the first time of the day. In order to bypass this, we usually run a Start Up script or so called Warm up script at a scheduled time at the beginning of the day. This refreshes the App pool and in turn the subsequent IIS requests come faster like normal.

The best Wake up script I have found is from codeplex called [SPWakeUp](http://spwakeup.codeplex.com/) script which comes handy with certain parameters like -Exclude(to exclude certain sites), -UserName, -Password required for accessing the sites, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The warmup scripts are meant to keep the SharePoint sites & its contents more responsive and some also for maintenance (recycling App pools & IIS). Here's an example - [Warming up SharePoint 2010 using PowerShell](http://sharepointryan.com/2011/03/29/warming-up-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/)

There's another post here that explains more - [SharePoint Site Collection Keep Alive Job](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2010/03/27/introducing-the-sharepoint-site-collection-keep-alive-job.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20AndrewConnell%20%28Andrew%20Connell%20%5BMVP%20SharePoint%5D%29)